# React update child's props after parent's state change

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to pass Draft.js's editor state from the editor component to my own `Sidebar` component.

Using the topmost component `Notes` I use a callback to get the editor state from `CustomEditor` and set it as the `Notes` state. I then pass that state to `Sidebar` as a prop.

The problem is that the prop is set before the callback fires. I was thinking a `setTimeout` but that seems rough. I'm aware of `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` but the docs don't recommend it. Is there something in react for this use case?

```
export class Notes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getEditorState = this.getEditorState.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      editorState: "the placeholder data Sidebar should not have as a prop"
    };
  }

  getEditorState(state) {
    console.log(state)
    this.setState({editorState: state})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section id="Notes">
        <div id="editor-holder">
          <Sidebar currentEditorState={this.state.editorState}/>
          <div id="Editor">
            <FileHeader />
            <CustomEditor getState={this.getEditorState}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }

}

export default Notes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Context API is the solution to this type of problem. Took a bit to get my head around it, but what I came up with gets `editorState` to `Sidebar` as a prop.

```
  export const NoteContext = React.createContext("placeholderEditorState");

  export class Notes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.getEditorState = this.getEditorState.bind(this)
      this.getFolderData = this.getFolderData.bind(this)
      this.state = {
        editorState: null,
        folderData: null
      };
    }

    getEditorState(state) {
      this.setState({editorState: state});
    }

    getFolderData(data) {
      this.setState({folderData : data})
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <section id="Notes">
          <TopBar />
          <div id="editor-holder">

            <NoteContext.Provider value={{editorState: this.state.editorState}} >
              <NoteContext.Consumer>
                {(context)=>{ return (
                  <Sidebar currentEditorState={context.editorState} getFolderData={this.getFolderData}/>
                )}}
              </NoteContext.Consumer>
            </NoteContext.Provider>

              <div id="Editor">

                <NoteContext.Provider value={{folderData: this.state.folderData}} >
                  <FileHeader />
                </NoteContext.Provider>

                <CustomEditor getState={this.getEditorState}/>
              </div>

          </div>
        </section>
      ); 
  }
}
```

Looking at it now it seems very straightforward, that means I've learnt a lot! Let me know if I can improve anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are more possible options how to achieve this result

## Conditional rendering

You can render `<Sidebar>` only when props has altered that menas

```
constructor(props)
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    editorState: false
  }
}

render() {
 ... {this.state.editorState && <Sidebar currentEditorState={this.state.editorState}/>}
}
```

## Guard component for undefined/false props

**Sidebar.js**

```
render() {
  if(!this.props.currentEditorState) return null // this will force React to render nothing

  return ( ... )
}
```

## Transition props to state with getDerivedState

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

**Sidebar.js**

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps({ currentEditorState }, prevState) {
  if(currentEditorState !== false {
   return { currentEditorState }
  } else {
   return {}
  }
}

render() {
  (.... something bound to this.state.currentEditorState)
}
```

## Use context (legacy context)

```
class Notes extends React.Component {
 getEditorState(state) {
    console.log(state)
    this.setState({editorState: state})
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      editorState: this.state.editorState
    }
  }

  childContextTypes = {
    editorState: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.obj, PropTypes.bool])
  }
}
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
class Sidebar {
  static contextTypes = {
    editorState: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.obj, PropTypes.bool])
  }

  render() {
    ... this.context.editorState
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming my use case is somewhat unique, then? Do you think there is a better way of designing my data flow?

Comment: Your case is perfectly normal, it's often to render childs with props `postponed` e.g when parent component act as data loader and pass props down. Same flow is done e.g. in modals where you have button which sets `state.isOpen` to the true, and child modal component opens. However passing state from one component to another looks like anti-pattern. I would consider to have centralised store as redux/mobx  or if you don't want to use that, you can use React `context` which shares the state automatically.

Comment: I'll look into `context` as a solution to this. It seems to be React's solution to this case.

Comment: From what I've read of the docs, you are using the old context API. Is that because the legacy context API is best for this case? I can understand that, the new API looks like a lot of work for this small problem. See https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html#updating-context

Comment: It’s “future” legacy. New one was introduced 30 days ago and I didnt test in production therefore I dont want to post code with which I am not familiar, but feel free to use new context ofcourse

Comment: I'll go down the rabbit whole of the new context API as it seems to be what I need if I can make it work. In the mean time thanks for the lead.